# How can I do to delete a row?

Tags: java

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
// TODO add your handling code here:   
 String sql = "DELETE  FROM `outil` WHERE nom_outil='outil B'";
  try{
      stmt=maconnexion.ObtenirConnexion().createStatement();
      stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
  }    
    catch(SQLException ex){
    System.err.println(ex);
    }    
}
```

I would want to know if there is another way without being obliged every time to go into my rêquête to change parameter. How make the professionals in computing in their application where we select any line of the table with the mouse then we press on the button to delete and that deletes right now.

Comment: Please try to confirm with the variable and package rules, lowercasing. And `Library` is both your package name as a variable name

Comment: can I have an example? Because I don't understand your answer.

Comment: Do you think is a bad method?

Comment: I make another question with update a row.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your `UPDATE` statement.

Try:

```
 String rty = "UPDATE Library SET skill='Comics'";
```

Comment: setString,getValueAt,getSelectedRow cannot still find  symbol according to netbaens.

Comment: @OscarPérez : Update ? which record ?. `WHERE ID =1000` e.g.